# How to specify interaction terms in python?

Tags: python, global-variables, stata

I have Stata code that I want to transform to python.
In Stata, the code reads as follows:

```
global controls_closed  i.closed##c.timeoff             i.closed##c.cards closed##c.subs  i.closed##c.goals
```

where closed, timeoff, cards, subs and goals are variables. My understanding is that i.closed transforms closed to an indicator variable, c signals a continuous variable.
What exactly is stored in this global $controls_closed?
These are interaction terms of the variables? But there is no dependent variable specified right?
If I sum the global, I obtain:

```
. sum $controls_closed

    Variable |        Obs        Mean    Std. dev.       Min        Max
-------------+---------------------------------------------------------
      closed |
          0  |     17,331    .8889851    .3141597          0          1
          1  |     17,331    .1110149    .3141597          0          1
     timeoff |     17,331    1197.085     191.682        443       1964
             |
      closed#|
   c.timeoff |
          0  |     17,331    1056.682    413.5998          0       1964
          1  |     17,331     140.403    403.0101          0       1931
```

What is the interpretation of this?
The global $controls_closed is later used in a regression,

```
reg extratime_sec $controls_closed , vce(cluster hometeam_id)
```

How can I do this in python? Is there a possibility to store the results from the interaction terms in a dictionary? And how to access this later on in the regression?

So far I tried the following:

```
controls_closed = [
'closed:timeoff + closed:cards + closed:subs + closed:fouls + closed:goals + closed:extra_pass_dist_losing + closed:extra_time_goals + closed:VAR + closed:max_number_games',
]


formula = "extratime_sec ~ " + " + ".join([f'{term}' for term in controls_closed])


model = sm.OLS.from_formula(formula, data=df)
result = model.fit(cov_type='cluster', cov_kwds={'groups': df['hometeam_id']})
```

This does not work as 'The weights and list don't have the same length.' Is there a good way to find out for which this holds?

Because if I run this regression for just a subset of variables, then it seems to work:

```
import statsmodels.api as sm

controls_closed = [
    'closed:timeoff', 'closed:subs', 'closed:goals',
]

formula = "extratime_sec ~ " + " + ".join([f'{term}' for term in controls_closed])

model = sm.OLS.from_formula(formula, data=df)

result = model.fit(cov_type='cluster', cov_kwds={'groups': df['hometeam_id']})

print(result.summary())
```

Comment: The `global` just contains the text you defined it as containing, in this case variable names, some flagged as categorical and some as continuous.

Comment: Take a look at section 11.4.3 [here](https://www.stata.com/manuals/u11.pdf) on what Stata is doing.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.